# Trying to add a click function to an image, makes the image disappear

Tags: jquery, css, html, image, effect

I'm trying to practice jQuery events and I want to click through some pictures while having an on click event, just to work with multiple effects.

Currently, I have an image that grows when it is hovered over, and then shrinks when mousedout.
Everything works until I uncomment the commented code in the jQuery. The image just disappears. I have tried just about everything I could think of, and I'm not sure where I went wrong.
I'm fairly new to jQuery and I'm teaching myself via tutorials and source code from other projects, so I wouldn't doubt if it was just something stupid on my part.
I would appreciate it if anyone could help me solve my problem. Bug fixing seems to be my weakest part of coding, so far.

```javascript
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var preloadImgs = ['imgs/ptilota.jpg',
                           'imgs/cell_division.jpg',
                           'imgs/lynx_spiders.jpg'];

        var imgs = [];
        for (var i=0; i<preloadImgs.length; i++) {
            imgs[i] = new Image();
            imgs[i].src = preloadImgs[i];
        }

        var photo = $('#photo');
        var imgVal = 0;

        photo.attr('src',preloadImgs[imgVal]);

        photo.hover(
            function() {
                $(this).stop().animate(
                    {
                        width: '1080px',
                        height: '682px'
                    }, 500
                );
            },

            function() {
                $(this).stop().animate(
                    {
                        width: '540px',
                        height: '341px'
                    }, 500
                );
            }
        );

        /* photo.click(

            function() {
                imgVal = imgVal + 1;

                 if (imgVal >= preloadImgs.length) {
                    imgVal = 0;
                } 

                photo.attr('src',preloadImgs[imgVal]);
            }
        ); */

    });
```

This is the HTML:

```html
<body>

<img src="" id="photo" />

</body>
```

Comment: could you make a jsfiddle?

Comment: [I made a jsfiddle of your exact code](http://jsfiddle.net/daCrosby/4yekb/) and it seems to work as expected.  Are you getting any errors in the console?

Comment: Maybe it's an image problem - can you verify all the links in `preloadImgs` are correct? Put them in `img` tags manually and ensure they load there.

Comment: Thank you so much, DACrosby, I checked it out and I had mislabeled the images. I feel so dumb sometimes. :S Answer it, so I can give you rep?